# Weird popup after triggering cmd + shift + a

Tags: macos, android-studio, intellij-idea

When trying to show the `Find Action` popup with `cmd + shift + a`, it shows a weird popup and can't do anything on Find Actions.

Anything I could do to remove this annoying behavior?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

**Additional information:**

Android Studio 3.3.2

Build #AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842, built on February 15, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01 x86_64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

macOS 10.14.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new system shortcut added in Mac OS 10.14.4. You can turn it off in System Preferences | Keyboard | Shortcut | Services.